# Create n data frames using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to name in a different way the data frames that I am going to create using the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

os.chdir("/Users/path")

dataframes=[]

paths =  glob.glob("*.csv")

for path in paths:
        dataset= pd.read_csv(path)
    dataframes.append(dataset)
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
df1
df2
df3
....
```

in order to use each of them for different analysis purposes. In the folder I have files like

```
analysis_for_market.csv, dataset_for_analysis.csv, test.csv, ...
```

Suppose I have `23` csv files (this length is given by dataframes as it appends each of df). 
For each of them I would like to create a dataframe df in python in order to run different analysis. 
I would do for one of it:

`df=pd.read_csv(path)` (where path is `"/path/analysis_for_market.csv"`). 
and then I could work on it (adding columns, dropping them, and so on). 
However, I would like also to be able to work with another dataset, let say `dataset_for_analysis.csv`, so I would need to create a new dataframe, `df2`. This could be useful in case I would like to compare rows. 
And so on. Potentially I would need a df for each dataset, so I would need `23 df`. 
I think it could be done using a for loop, but I have not idea on how to call the df(for example, execute `df.describe` for the two examples above). 
Could you please tell me how to do this?
If you find a possible question related to mine, could you please add it in a comment, before closing my question (as a previous post was closed before solving my issues)?

Thank you for your help and understanding.

Update:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

os.chdir("/Users/path")

paths =  glob.glob("*.csv")

dataframes=[]

df={}
for x in range(1,len(paths)):
    for path in paths:
            df["0".format(x)]=pd.read_csv(path)

        #dataframes[path] = df # it gives me the following error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

df["2"]
```

it works only for `0` as in the code, but I do not know how to let the value ranges between `1` and `len(paths)`

Comment: I added a possible solution. unfortunately I do not know how to span from `0` to `len(paths)` in `df["0".format(x)]`. It correctly represent only the first dataset as it is set to `0`.

Comment: I think you are missing some braces.`"{0}".format(x)` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the name of dataframe will do the job.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

os.chdir("/Users/path")

df = {}

paths =  glob.glob("*.csv")

for index, path in enumerate(paths):
      df[str(index)]= pd.read_csv(path)
```

This is working fine for me. If i call df['0'], this is giving me the first dataframe.

Comment: Hi Manoj, unfortunately your code above is not doing what I am looking for as it takes as name the path and a single path is a long csv file name. I would need something that can enumerate my data frames

Comment: Hey I have updated two lines, please check that. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global variable with any name you like by doing

```
"globals()["df32"] = ..."
```

But that is usually viewed as poor coding practice (because you might be clobbering existing names without knowing it).
Instead, just create a dictionary `mydfs` (say) and do   `mydfs[1]=...`

Answer (score 0):

```py
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd
for i, path in enumerate(glob('*.csv')):
    exec("{} = {}".format("df{0:03d}".format(i), pd.read_csv(path, encoding = 'latin-1')))
```

You can adjust the `0:03d` bit to the number of leading zeros you'd like if you need to or can just skip it alltogether with `df{i}`.

Comment: Hi Ramin. I have tried your code but unfortunately I am getting the following error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Comment: @LucaDiMauro I updated it. Try it out. If that won't work, then I think you better off creating a dictionary and then make the `i` a key and your data frame a value.

Comment: Unfortunately there is an error with invalid syntax when it reads   File "<string>"

Comment: @LucaDiMauro Maybe it has to do with encoding. Try either removing the `, encoding = 'latin-1'` part or change the encoding to `utf8`.